How to overlap the boundaries of widgets in flutter
Ok so I apologize if the title of the question is confusing but see this:

So there is a blue container in the bottom left and 2 in top right corner of the main grey container. How do implement something like this in flutter. I am guessing there are two columns here one for left side panel and one for main grey container in right. How to make those blue containers as shown in the image that is part of both the columns?
I found there is a widget named OverflowBox, Maybe I can put this widget as a child in the main grey container but how would it overlap the left column and also how do I make it appear as a separate widget with those rounded corners between them

Quick question, are you making this for web?

@shimomaru Yes, I just saw this online and wanted to try making it but could not figure how

It can be done using Stack() and calculated positions.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomWidget> createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  // White container dimensions
  final double mainContainerHeight = 600;
  final double mainContainerWidth = 900;
  final double mainContainerPadding = 16.0;

  // Inner grey container dimensions
  final double customContainerWidth = 600;
  final double customContainerHeight = 600;

  final double cuttingEdgeHeight = 40;
  final double cornerRadius = 20.0;

  // Multiplier to determine the width of the cutting edge in the grey container
  final double cuttingEdgeWidthMultiplier = 0.32;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: mainContainerHeight,
            maxWidth: mainContainerWidth,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(mainContainerPadding),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              // Top right blue container
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: customContainerWidth * cuttingEdgeWidthMultiplier,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(width: 4),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          height: cuttingEdgeHeight - 4,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Center grey container with custom clip
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: MyClipper(
                    cuttingEdgeHeight: cuttingEdgeHeight,
                    cuttingEdgeWidth: customContainerWidth * cuttingEdgeWidthMultiplier,
                    cornerRadius: cornerRadius,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    width: customContainerWidth,
                    height: customContainerHeight,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Bottom left blue container
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: SizedBox(
                  // Calculate the width of the bottom left blue container
                  // The available width is the difference between the main container and grey container widths
                  // plus the cutting edge width minus the padding on both sides
                  width: (mainContainerWidth - customContainerWidth) +
                         (customContainerWidth * cuttingEdgeWidthMultiplier) -
                         (mainContainerPadding * 2),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          height: cuttingEdgeHeight - 4,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 4),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Custom clipper class to create the custom grey container with arcs and bends
class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double cuttingEdgeWidth;
  final double cornerRadius;
  final double cuttingEdgeHeight;
  MyClipper({
    required this.cuttingEdgeWidth,
    required this.cornerRadius,
    required this.cuttingEdgeHeight,
  });

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {

    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(cornerRadius, 0) // Start with a slight offset to accommodate the top-left arc
      ..lineTo(size.width - cuttingEdgeWidth - cornerRadius, 0) // Draw a line to the top-right corner
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width - cuttingEdgeWidth, 0, size.width - cuttingEdgeWidth, cornerRadius) // Draw the top-right arc

      ..lineTo(size.width - cuttingEdgeWidth, cuttingEdgeHeight - cornerRadius) // Draw a line down stopping short of the inner arc
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width - cuttingEdgeWidth, cuttingEdgeHeight, size.width - cuttingEdgeWidth + cornerRadius, cuttingEdgeHeight) // Draw the inner top-right arc

      ..lineTo(size.width - cornerRadius, cuttingEdgeHeight) // Draw the line to the far right stopping short of the corner
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, cuttingEdgeHeight, size.width, cuttingEdgeHeight + cornerRadius) // Draw the outer top-right arc
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - cornerRadius) // Draw a line down stopping short of the bottom-right arc
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height, size.width - cornerRadius, size.height) // Draw the bottom-right arc

      ..lineTo(cuttingEdgeWidth + cornerRadius, size.height) // Draw a line to the left side of the bottom-left corner
      ..quadraticBezierTo(cuttingEdgeWidth, size.height, cuttingEdgeWidth, size.height - cornerRadius) // Draw the bottom-left arc

      ..lineTo(cuttingEdgeWidth, size.height - cuttingEdgeHeight + cornerRadius) // Draw the line up stopping short of the inner arc
      ..quadraticBezierTo(cuttingEdgeWidth, size.height - cuttingEdgeHeight, cuttingEdgeWidth - cornerRadius, size.height - cuttingEdgeHeight) // Draw the inner bottom-left arc

      ..lineTo(cornerRadius, size.height - cuttingEdgeHeight) // Draw the line to the left stopping short of the bottom-left corner
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height - cuttingEdgeHeight, 0, size.height - cuttingEdgeHeight - cornerRadius) // Draw the bottom-left arc

      ..lineTo(0, cornerRadius) // Draw a line up stopping short of the final top-left arc
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, cornerRadius, 0) // Draw the final top-left arc
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}


Try running this in Chrome.
Note: This design is not responsive, so it may display differently when the window width is reduced.

Thank you so much, It is working. I will just play around with the code to understand it better.
